# No puedo realizar una tarea que deseo con un bucle for

Tags: javascript, css, html5

tengo unas tablas de multiplicar que quiero mostrar en el DOM pero quiero que se generen con javaScript para eso hice un bucle for que saque tablas de multiplicar segun quiera el usuario pero quiero que al a la la multiplicacion de xnumero x 10 = resultado me ingrese las otras multiplicaciones en un nuevo div ¿como lo hago?.

```js
const tablasDiv = document.querySelector('#tablas');
const form = document.querySelector('#multipli');


form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let tablas = {
        tabla: document.querySelector('#tabla').value,
        numero: document.querySelector('#numMax').value
    }


    for (let i = 0; i <= tablas.numero; i++) {

        let p = document.createElement('p');
        let total = tablas.tabla * i;

        p.append(`${tablas.tabla} x ${i} = ${total}`)
        tablasDiv.append(p)
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/mian.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Tablas de Multiplicar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="cabecera">
        <h1 class="title">Multiplicaciones</h1>
        <form id="multipli">

            <div>
                <label>Tabla</label>
                <input type="number" id="tabla">
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <label>Numeros</label>
                <input type="number" id="numMax">
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Obtener</button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <main id="global">
        <section class="slide">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </section>
        <section id="tablas">

        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

ya edite aqui esta mi html como les digo no se como lograr hacer lo que quiero ojala y me puedan ayudar

Comment: Sería bueno ver el HTML. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/586022/edit) tu pregunta y agregarlo.

Comment: Supongo que quieres varias tablas de multiplicar, cada una con un máximo de 10x10 elementos, es así?

Comment: Yo lo que no entiendo es el resultado esperado, puedes dar un ejemplo de eso?

Comment: exacto serian divs con un máximo de 10x10 y que si el usuario desea que la tabla por ejemplo del 2 llegue a multiplicarse hasta el 30 que entonces cuando el bucle llegue al valor 10 que cree otro div que solo contenga la misma tabla del  pero hasta 2x20 y luego al llegar al 2x20 cree otro div que contenga desde 2x21 hasta el 2x30 y así sucesivamente

Comment: Ejemplo usuario pide tabla del 2 que se multiplica hasta 20 resultado: <div> 2x1 =2 2x2 =2 2x3 =6 2x4=8 2x5=10 2x6=12 2x7=14 2x8=16 2x9=18 2x10=20 </div> </div>2x11=22 2x12=24 2x13=26 2x14=28 2x15=30 2x16=32 2x17=34 2x18=36 2x19=38 2x20=40</div> ese seria la respuesta

Comment: Primero que nada @Danah, las aclaraciones en vez de en comentarios ponlas en la propia pregunta por favor. Y segundo... puedes hacerlo con un único bucle si compruebas `i % 10 === 0` (básicamente el resto de i entre 10 === 0 significa que el número es divisible por 10, ergo 10, 20, 30...), cuando eso da true creas un nuevo div y ya está. Tendrás que tener cuidado con los extremos (por ejemplo, si solo quiero ver 10 números no tiene sentido crear un nuevo div para no meterle luego nada :)) pero es factible!

Comment: ¿Porque no creas un div a parte con id del primer input?: <div id="tablas"><div id="tabla-2"><p>0x2=0</p><p>1x2=2</p><p>2x2=4</p></div>, En js: let t=document.getElementById("tabla-"+tabla.tabla) | ducment.createElement("div"); t.setAttribute("id","tabla-"+tabla.tabla);tablasDiv.appendChild(t);for(...){...;t.appendChild(p);

Comment: Puedes hacerlo fácilmente comprobando si es múltiplo de 10 `i % 10 == 0` y creas un nuevo div...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que ocupar el operador `%` ([remanente](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)), esto te entrega los que sobra de una división entera, por ejemplo

- 10 % 3 = 1

Es decir el 3 cabe 3 veces en el 10 y sobra 1.

Un casó tipico es encontrar los pares que se realiza con

- numero % 2 == 0

Porque cualquier número que en su división por 2 tenga un remanente cero es par.

Bajo esta misma logica, en tu caso para obtenter bloque de 10 en 10, necesitas hacer

- i % 10 == 0

Además de ir creando un bloque nuevo cada vez que pasa eso.

Por ejemplo

```js
const global = document.querySelector('#global');
const form = document.querySelector('#multipli');


form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let tablas = {
        tabla: document.querySelector('#tabla').value,
        numero: document.querySelector('#numMax').value
    }

     let seccion = document.createElement("section"); //creamos el primer bloque
        global.append(seccion); //lo añadimos al padre
        
    for (let i = 0; i <= tablas.numero; i++) {

        let p = document.createElement('p');
        let total = tablas.tabla * i;   
        p.append(`${tablas.tabla} x ${i} = ${total}`)
     
        if(i%10==0){ 
           seccion = document.createElement("section"); //volvemos a crear un bloque
           global.append(seccion); //lo añadimos al padre
        }

        seccion.append(p)
    }
})
```

```css
/* solo por la demo*/
section:not(.slide) {
 border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/mian.css">
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Tablas de Multiplicar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="cabecera">
        <h1 class="title">Multiplicaciones</h1>
        <form id="multipli">

            <div>
                <label>Tabla</label>
                <input type="number" id="tabla">
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <label>Numeros</label>
                <input type="number" id="numMax">
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Obtener</button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <main id="global">
        <section class="slide">
            <img src="" alt="">
        </section>

    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió mucho solo lo adapte a lo que necesitaba y listo te lo agradezco

Comment: Una solución ingeniosa, sin duda. +1